# Comparing empty list from JSON to an empty list

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I am trying to check in JavaScript if a value from a json is an empty list or not.
I tried obviously json.bundleProductSummaries != []. This doesn't work, however this works:

```
JSON.stringify(json.bundleProductSummaries) != JSON.stringify([])
```

My json :

```
  {
    "bundleProductSummaries": [

    ]
  }
```

My code :

```
fs = require('fs')
body = fs.readFileSync('./json.txt',{encoding : 'utf-8'})
// ---- Parsing de body ----
let json = JSON.parse(body);
let colored = null;

if(json.bundleProductSummaries != []){
    json = json.bundleProductSummaries[0];
}
```

Thank you for your future answers !
Syndorik

Comment: What is problem. Do you want to know the explanation of the code...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to check length

```
json.bundleProductSummaries.length === 0
```

Because in JS

```js
console.log([] === [] )
```

as they are two different memory reference.

> But when two array will evaluate to true ?

When they both the value you're comparing is having same reference

```js
let a = []

console.log(a === a)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So basically, it behaves like a pointer in C? I suppose this is also the case for dict and other structures like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) of the Array to check if its empty

```js
let obj = {
    "bundleProductSummaries": []
}
console.log(obj.bundleProductSummaries.length === 0)
```

In you case you can just don't need to compare because you are using it in `if` statement and `0` is itself a falsy value.

```js
let obj = {
   "bundleProductSummaries": []
}
if(!obj.bundleProductSummaries.length){
  console.log("Array is empty")
}
```